# Append all queries in a group as a New Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have placed all the queries that I want to append as a new query in one group. I might add a few more in the future. So is there a way we can edit the code to include all the queries in the group

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's currently possible to do this exactly how you want, but there are some possible workarounds.

One possibility is to use the `#shared` space and pick out the tables that you want. Try playing around with the query below where `{"Column1", "Column2", ... }` is the list of column names in the group of queries that you want to append together.

```
let
    Shared = Record.ToTable(#shared),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Shared, "Custom", each try Table.ColumnNames([Value]) = {"Column1", "Column2", ... }),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Value"}, {"HasCols"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Custom", each ([HasCols] = true)),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Value", {"Column1", "Column2", ... }, {"Column1", "Column2", ... })
in
    #"Expanded Value"
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on #shared space. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: It's a bit obscure and I don't know a ton about it, but I'd suggest reading this: http://radacad.com/power-query-library-of-functions-shared-keyword

Comment: thank you for the web link. That was a really great tip.